# AMP Email - amp-selector to create a conditional menu

Tags: html-email, amp-html, amp-email

Does any one know how to make a conditional hide with amp-selector in email? on buttons like these? So I have 3 of these buttons next to each other, menu 1, menu 2 and menu 3. So if I click menu1, I only want the content to show that links to menu 1.. If I click menu2 I want to only show the content from menu2 and so forth.

```
   <table>
     <tr>
       <th on="tap:menu1.hide;tap:menu1.toggleVisibility"  class="bg-indigo-500 hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded" style="mso-padding-alt: 12px 48px;">
         <a class="block text-white text-sm leading-full py-12 px-48 no-underline">Menu 1</a>
       </th>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

```
<amp-selector id="menu1" layout="container"  hidden>


  <amp-selector id="hide1" layout="container" name="single_image_select" >
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p  option="1"  select>   MENU1    </p>
          </li>
      <li>
          <p  option="2" hidden>   HEJ2    </p>
      </li>
      <li option="na" disabled>None of the Above</li>
    </ul>
  </amp-selector>
</amp-selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use actions and events in AMP Email to achieve this. See [this URL](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-email-actions-and-events/?format=email) for detail.

**Below is a tested code for the same:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡4email>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>
  <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-selector" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-selector-0.1.js"></script>

  <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
  <style amp4email-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden} </style>
   <style amp-custom>
      /* any custom styles go here. */
      .hideme {
        visibility:hidden
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

  <button value="menu1" on="tap:menu1.toggleVisibility,menu2.hide,menu3.hide">menu1</button>
  <button value="menu1" on="tap:menu2.toggleVisibility,menu1.hide,menu3.hide">menu2</button>
  <button value="menu1" on="tap:menu3.toggleVisibility,menu1.hide,menu2.hide">menu3</button>
  
<div id="menu1">
  <h3>
     Menu1
  </h3>
  <amp-list
    width="auto"
    height="100"
    layout="fixed-height"
    src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/inline-examples/data/amp-list-urls.json"
   >

    <template type="amp-mustache">

      <div class="url-entry">
        <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
      </div>
    </template>
  </amp-list>
</div>    

<div id="menu2" hidden>
  <h3>
     Menu2
  </h3>
  <amp-list
    width="auto"
    height="100"
    layout="fixed-height"
    src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/inline-examples/data/amp-list-urls.json"
   >

    <template type="amp-mustache">

      <div class="url-entry">
        <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
      </div>
    </template>
  </amp-list>
</div>   

<div id="menu3" hidden>
  <h3>
     Menu3
  </h3>
  <amp-list
    width="auto"
    height="100"
    layout="fixed-height"
    src="https://preview.amp.dev/static/inline-examples/data/amp-list-urls.json"
   >

    <template type="amp-mustache">

      <div class="url-entry">
        <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
      </div>
    </template>
  </amp-list>
</div>   


</body>
</html>
```

[Working Example in AMP Playground](https://playground.amp.dev/?runtime=amp4email#share=PCFkb2N0eXBlIGh0bWw+CjxodG1sIOKaoTRlbWFpbD4KPGhlYWQ+CjxtZXRhIGNoYXJzZXQ9InV0Zi04Ij4KICA8c2NyaXB0IGFzeW5jIHNyYz0iaHR0cHM6Ly9jZG4uYW1wcHJvamVjdC5vcmcvdjAuanMiPjwvc2NyaXB0PgogIDxzY3JpcHQgYXN5bmMgY3VzdG9tLWVsZW1lbnQ9ImFtcC1saXN0IiBzcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmFtcHByb2plY3Qub3JnL3YwL2FtcC1saXN0LTAuMS5qcyI+PC9zY3JpcHQ+CiAgPHNjcmlwdCBhc3luYyBjdXN0b20tdGVtcGxhdGU9ImFtcC1tdXN0YWNoZSIgc3JjPSJodHRwczovL2Nkbi5hbXBwcm9qZWN0Lm9yZy92MC9hbXAtbXVzdGFjaGUtMC4yLmpzIj48L3NjcmlwdD4KICA8c2NyaXB0IGFzeW5jIGN1c3RvbS1lbGVtZW50PSJhbXAtc2VsZWN0b3IiIHNyYz0iaHR0cHM6Ly9jZG4uYW1wcHJvamVjdC5vcmcvdjAvYW1wLXNlbGVjdG9yLTAuMS5qcyI+PC9zY3JpcHQ+CgogIDxzY3JpcHQgYXN5bmMgY3VzdG9tLWVsZW1lbnQ9ImFtcC1iaW5kIiBzcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmFtcHByb2plY3Qub3JnL3YwL2FtcC1iaW5kLTAuMS5qcyI+PC9zY3JpcHQ+CiAgPHN0eWxlIGFtcDRlbWFpbC1ib2lsZXJwbGF0ZT5ib2R5e3Zpc2liaWxpdHk6aGlkZGVufSA8L3N0eWxlPgogICA8c3R5bGUgYW1wLWN1c3RvbT4KICAgICAgLyogYW55IGN1c3RvbSBzdHlsZXMgZ28gaGVyZS4gKi8KICAgICAgLmhpZGVtZSB7CiAgICAgICAgdmlzaWJpbGl0eTpoaWRkZW4KICAgICAgfQogICAgPC9zdHlsZT4KPC9oZWFkPgo8Ym9keT4KCiAgPGJ1dHRvbiB2YWx1ZT0ibWVudTEiIG9uPSJ0YXA6bWVudTEudG9nZ2xlVmlzaWJpbGl0eSxtZW51Mi5oaWRlLG1lbnUzLmhpZGUiPm1lbnUxPC9idXR0b24+CiAgPGJ1dHRvbiB2YWx1ZT0ibWVudTEiIG9uPSJ0YXA6bWVudTIudG9nZ2xlVmlzaWJpbGl0eSxtZW51MS5oaWRlLG1lbnUzLmhpZGUiPm1lbnUyPC9idXR0b24+CiAgPGJ1dHRvbiB2YWx1ZT0ibWVudTEiIG9uPSJ0YXA6bWVudTMudG9nZ2xlVmlzaWJpbGl0eSxtZW51MS5oaWRlLG1lbnUyLmhpZGUiPm1lbnUzPC9idXR0b24+CiAgCjxkaXYgaWQ9Im1lbnUxIj4KICA8aDM+CiAgICAgTWVudTEKICA8L2gzPgogIDxhbXAtbGlzdAogICAgd2lkdGg9ImF1dG8iCiAgICBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCIKICAgIGxheW91dD0iZml4ZWQtaGVpZ2h0IgogICAgc3JjPSJodHRwczovL3ByZXZpZXcuYW1wLmRldi9zdGF0aWMvaW5saW5lLWV4YW1wbGVzL2RhdGEvYW1wLWxpc3QtdXJscy5qc29uIgogICA+CgogICAgPHRlbXBsYXRlIHR5cGU9ImFtcC1tdXN0YWNoZSI+CgogICAgICA8ZGl2IGNsYXNzPSJ1cmwtZW50cnkiPgogICAgICAgIDxhIGhyZWY9Int7dXJsfX0iPnt7dGl0bGV9fTwvYT4KICAgICAgPC9kaXY+CiAgICA8L3RlbXBsYXRlPgogIDwvYW1wLWxpc3Q+CjwvZGl2PiAgICAKCjxkaXYgaWQ9Im1lbnUyIiBoaWRkZW4+CiAgPGgzPgogICAgIE1lbnUyCiAgPC9oMz4KICA8YW1wLWxpc3QKICAgIHdpZHRoPSJhdXRvIgogICAgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAiCiAgICBsYXlvdXQ9ImZpeGVkLWhlaWdodCIKICAgIHNyYz0iaHR0cHM6Ly9wcmV2aWV3LmFtcC5kZXYvc3RhdGljL2lubGluZS1leGFtcGxlcy9kYXRhL2FtcC1saXN0LXVybHMuanNvbiIKICAgPgoKICAgIDx0ZW1wbGF0ZSB0eXBlPSJhbXAtbXVzdGFjaGUiPgoKICAgICAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0idXJsLWVudHJ5Ij4KICAgICAgICA8YSBocmVmPSJ7e3VybH19Ij57e3RpdGxlfX08L2E+CiAgICAgIDwvZGl2PgogICAgPC90ZW1wbGF0ZT4KICA8L2FtcC1saXN0Pgo8L2Rpdj4gICAKCjxkaXYgaWQ9Im1lbnUzIiBoaWRkZW4+CiAgPGgzPgogICAgIE1lbnUzCiAgPC9oMz4KICA8YW1wLWxpc3QKICAgIHdpZHRoPSJhdXRvIgogICAgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAiCiAgICBsYXlvdXQ9ImZpeGVkLWhlaWdodCIKICAgIHNyYz0iaHR0cHM6Ly9wcmV2aWV3LmFtcC5kZXYvc3RhdGljL2lubGluZS1leGFtcGxlcy9kYXRhL2FtcC1saXN0LXVybHMuanNvbiIKICAgPgoKICAgIDx0ZW1wbGF0ZSB0eXBlPSJhbXAtbXVzdGFjaGUiPgoKICAgICAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0idXJsLWVudHJ5Ij4KICAgICAgICA8YSBocmVmPSJ7e3VybH19Ij57e3RpdGxlfX08L2E+CiAgICAgIDwvZGl2PgogICAgPC90ZW1wbGF0ZT4KICA8L2FtcC1saXN0Pgo8L2Rpdj4gICAKCgo8L2JvZHk+CjwvaHRtbD4=)